# Update entry from forEach if found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently doing like this, it find matching `Id` between message line and product line, if found then add Status.

```
var order = {
  "Products": [
   {"id": 123, "Status": []},
   {"id": 463, "Status": []},
  ]
}

var message = {
  "lines": [
   {"id": 535},
   {"id": 463},
  ]
}

const updateStatus = function(order, message, name) {
    var products = order.Products;
    message.lines.forEach((messageLine) => {
        products.forEach((item) => {
          if (products.Id == messageLine.Id) {
              item.Status.push({"Name": name});
          }
        });
    });

    console.log(order)
}

updateStatus(order, message, "Done");
```

I am not sure if this is a bad practice, is there a better way?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nv1cukw8/20/

Comment: Would be a good idea to post the data, what do you think?

Comment: Is your code not working or are you just looking for "best practices"?

Comment: @Ivan I have updated with Example. It is somewhat not working as it is adding Status twice, im also looking for "best practices" as well.

Comment: @baao posted data sample

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if an entry exists with the same id. This will stop on the first match and we don't have a forEach in a forEach. Also, as you want to update the order array's contents (Status), I'd use that as the principle looped array. If `messages.lines` contains millions of lines and you have only one Product, you can save some time.

```js
order.Products.forEach(product => {
    if (message.lines.some(({id}) => id === product.id)) {
        product.Status.push('whatever');
    }
});

console.log(order.Products)
```

```html
<script>
var order = {
    "Products": [
        {"id": 123, "Status": []},
        {"id": 463, "Status": []},
    ]
}

var message = {
    "lines": [
        {"id": 535},
        {"id": 463},
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: That work great, thank you. What caused from my example that being added twice on the status?

Answer (score -1):

I would go with something like this:
I modified the push line, because the push returns the index that was pushed. But I'm not aware if that was what you want.

```
products.filter(
  product => message.lines.filter(
    messageLine => 
      product.id == messageLine.id
  ).length > 0
).forEach(
  item => item.Status.push({'Name': name})
)
```